# Is any API for Google web stories?

Tags: google-api

I want to integrate Google web stories to my website using API. is there any API available to fetch google web stories?

If not, what could be an alternative to showing web stories on the website?

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/enable-web-stories#create

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Web Stories API

The API Reference [https://webstories.today/api/v1/docs]

And NuGet Package if you work with .Net
[https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeHelper.API.WebStories]

Comment: API is not free

Comment: Yes, the API is free, but only when you want to create and publish web stories, it is not free.
You can search, etc for free, you simply need an API key

Comment: Sadly I didn't find any. If u know some sites Please let me know. I didn't find any site publishing web stories via API (Free).

Comment: Publishing and free, no, but cheap yes

Answer (score 0):

When researching how to use web stories with Next.js, I found this tutorial on the official AMP website:
https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/visual_story/

You can use the `amp-story` component to create Web Stories with AMP.